# How to delete filter text from textbox with buttonclick

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am trying to delete filter text from a textbox but so far I have been unable to do this.  I have a collectionview filter that is working fine.  When I added a button to clear the filter and text in the filter textbox the collection filter is cleared and full collection is displayed but the text for the old filter is still displayed. I am using prism with this project.

Here is the part of the code for the filter and to clear the filter.

```
    class ScripterViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ScripterViewModel()
    {
        ScripterModel scripterModel = new ScripterModel();
        KeysToChoose = new ObservableCollection<Keys>();



        this.AddItemBtn = new DelegateCommand<Keys>(addItem);
        this.AddTextBtn = new DelegateCommand(addText);
        this.ClearSearchBtn = new DelegateCommand(ClearSearch);

        SelectedOption = "Lathe Keys";


        ItemsView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => Filter(o as Keys));
    }

    private bool Filter(Keys keys)
    {
        return Search == null
            || keys.Description.IndexOf(Search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;
    }

    public ICollectionView ItemsView
    {
        get
        {
            return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(KeysToChoose);
        }
    }            
    
    private string _search;

    public string Search
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _search; 
        }
        set
        {
            _search = value;
            SetProperty(ref _search, value);
            ItemsView.Refresh();
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
    public bool CanClearSearch()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public ICommand ClearSearchBtn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void ClearSearch()
    {
        if (Search != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Search = "";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error: '{0}'", e);
            }

        }
    }
```

Adding some xaml code
The textbox names SearchText is what I would like to clear with the button click.

```
            </TabControl>
        <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=ClipBoardText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="502" Height="25" IsEnabled="False" />
        <TextBox x:Name="SearchText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="48,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Search, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="502" RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,1.085"/>
        <Button x:Name="ClearSearchBtn" Content="Clear Search" Command="{Binding Path=ClearSearchBtn}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.371,-0.704" Visibility="Visible"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can You give me xaml code? I don't see the problem just from the viewModel.

Comment: @i-code I added the XAML code for the textbox and button I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ClearSearchBtn doesn't work because your Search doesn't trigger PropertyChanged.
- SetProperty(ref _search, value) :The internal working logic is that PropertyChanged is triggered only when the value changes.

search repeat set value

```
private string _search;

public string Search
{
    get 
    { 
        return _search; 
    }
    set
    {
        _search = value;// remove this
        SetProperty(ref _search, value);
        ItemsView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I thought that the setproperty caused the trigger.

Comment: `SetProperty` does nothing if the new value is the same as the old value (which is always the case with `_search = value;`). It also returns a `bool` that's true, if the value changed, so most of the time you'll write `if (SetProperty(...)) { /* notify other listeners */ }`